# How to sum up a two dimensional pulp solution

Tags: python, list, indexing, linear-programming, pulp

I have following code cutouts:

```
        a = range(0, 30)
        b = range (0, 88)
         Power_consumption =  LpVariable.dicts('Power_consumption', (a,b), lowBound=0, upBound=5, cat='Continuous')
    ...

result= [[]]
    for i in a:
        for j in b:
            print("i:",3, "j:",3, " = ", Power_consumption[i][j].varValue)
            result[i][j] = Power_consumption[i][j].varValue
```

After getting the optmimal solution of the Linear Programming Model, I would like to sum up the "Power_consumption" on the index i ( i = timestep, j = device) so that I have for every timestep "i" the power consumption of all devices. But when trying I get all the time "IndexError: list assignment index out of range". So I am wondering what I did wrong and whats the best way of doing so ?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think you are constructing your variable correctly with respect to `a` and `b`.  Be more explicit there…

```
a = list(range(30))
b = list(range(88))
ab = [(i, j) for i in a for j in b]
Power = LpVariable.dicts(‘power’, ab, . . . )
```